# Does google Analytics do any kind of reporting on ajax dynamic content?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

All my dynamic pages use a `#!` hashtag.

Does google analytics offer any kind of reporting on dynamic content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell GA to [register a url](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55597). So just use this in combination with  `window.location` whenever you make an AJAX call.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some-page']);
```

You may find the [GA API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi.html) useful for questions like this.

Comment: thanks! just a question what can I put in `/some-page`. If I write the hash for example such as: `/#!whatever1`,`/#!whatever2` will that get tracked? Or do I simply make up a page using the hash? Like `/p/whatever1`. Thanks

Comment: Also do you know if I must include: `var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);` before it? Thanks anyway

Comment: No, you don't need the `var gaq`. That is the initial tracking object that gets created. You then push new information to it. The passed page url must start with a slash. You can pass in whatever valid url syntax you want. `/#hash` is fine.